# Hibernate sets ID to null

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a problem where Hibernate resets the IDs for entities even though I explicitly set them.

Here are my two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private String token;

    private Set<DealersCard> dealersCards;

    @Id
    @Size(min=36, max=36)
    @Column(name="token")
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,  cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<DealersCard> getDealersCards() {
        return dealersCards;
    }

    public void setDealersCards(Set<DealersCard> dealersCards) {
        this.dealersCards = dealersCards;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dealers_card")
public class DealersCard implements Serializable {

    private String token;
    private int id;

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("token")
    @JoinColumn(name="token", referencedColumnName="token")
    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Id
    @Size(min = 36, max = 36)
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of Game with a two DealersCard assigned through EntityManager::persist the objects are created in the database correctly and I can retrieve them later, but if I retrieve an instance of Game, add another instance of DealersCard and try to update the database with EntityManager::merge, Hibernate, for some reason, sets the token field to null and id to 0 and I get

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: null
>   value in column "token" violates not-null constraint   Detail: Failing
>   row contains (null, 0).

I tried MySQL and PostgreSQL but I still encounter the same error. I am running Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Hibernate Entity Manager 4.1.2, Java EE 6.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not convinced your mappings are quite correct. You should probably have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,  cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "game")
private Set<DealersCard>
```

and on the many side:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="token")
private Game game;
```

Then remove the token field from the many side and just have an integer which is your @Id.

Ensure that when you add new DealerCards to your set that you set the game on each one as well as adding them to the collection.

Comment: You were absolutely right - the problem was with mappings. Thanks!